# Joining a list of object values into a string using list comprehensions in python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of objects.  In a single line I would like to create a string that contains a specific variable of each object in the list, separated by commas.

Right now I'm able to achieve this using a combination of list comprehensions and map like so:

```
','.join(map(str, [instance.public_dns_name for instance in instances]))
```

or using lambda:

```
','.join(map(str, [(lambda(i): i.public_dns_name)(instance) for instance in instances]))
```

Each instance object has a "public_dns_name" variable that returns the host name. This returns a string like this:

```
host1,host2,hos3,host4
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing using only the list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use *just* a list comprehension, you'll still need to use `join`.

It's more efficient to use a generator expression

```
','.join(str(instance.public_dns_name) for instance in instances)
```

A list comprehension would look like this:

```
','.join([str(instance.public_dns_name) for instance in instances])
```

The difference is that it creates the entire list in memory before joining, whereas the generator expression will create the components as they are joined

Comment: Not always more efficient to do so. For short lists, the overhead of the generator is more significant than the memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "only the list comprehension", you should still use `join` ultimately, but the process can be far less convoluted:

```
','.join(str(instance.public_dns_name) for instance in instances)
```

No need to create a lambda function here. And remember that `join` takes any *iterable*, so you don't have to create a list just to pass it to `join`.